# Fetching results from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

I am trying to query my mySQL database and want all rows returning in an array which is accessible in a way like.

```
rows[0]["column"]
rows[1]["column"].
```

My code is currently:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

var rows = dt.AsEnumerable().ToArray();
```

So I can use rows[0]["column"] but rows[1] is out of reach, as if the dt.Load hasn't scanned all rows and added them to the list.

Comment: A DataTable Rows collection is already an array, why do you need this extra level and the AsEnumerable added work? (By the way, _out of reach_ means _index out of range_ ? If so, what is the dt.Rows.Count value after the dt.Load command?

Comment: It only ever returns 1 row. However, I run the same query directly in MySQL and it returns 16 rows. I don't know why "AsEnumerable" - it was supplied to me in another piece of code I asked for help with. I just need all the results in an array from MySQL.

Comment: It seems strange. Are you sure that you are querying the same database? What is the query text executed?

Comment: You guys are correct. It's been me! - I've been banging my head on this for hours, thinking my query was correct, but it actually wasn't. So the rows was actually zero, so the code was correct. 

Sorry for the question. Thanks for assisting, as you actually did :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you some pseudo code here, I did not try to compile it but should give you the idea, in general do not use static indexes like "1" to access the second row in the table, better have a loop or some other kind of dynamic approach which would always work no matter on how many records your query returns.

look at this, omitted exception handling for compactness

```
using(var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ComamndText = query;

    var adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    var dt = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(dt);

    // here you can use the table's rows array to retrieve results
    // for example

    foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
    {
        //Do what you want now with this row
    }
}
```